# Office web component 11 - ActiveX component cant create object

Tags: com, vb6, asp-classic, office-web-components

I have an classic ASP application which calls a VB6 ActiveX DLL component. The DLL uses Office web component (v11.0) to create a spreadsheet. I'm getting an error when i try to create an instance of OWC11 Spreadsheet.

```
Dim oSS As OWC11.Spreadsheet
Set oSS = New OWC11.Spreadsheet ' ActiveX component can't create object(error id 429)
```

The following code works perfectly in my Test environment, but fails in my production server. Both my Test and Prod environment uses Windows Server 2003 SE.

Additional information:

- OWC11.DLL version - 12.0.6502.5000 in test environment
- OWC11.DLL version - 12.0.4518.1014 in prod environment

The following service packs are updated in the Production server

- KB976569
- KB979909
- KB980773
- KB976765
- KB976576
- KB981793

Can this issue be due to the Service Pack updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling the OWC11 package on the server?

It sounds like one or more of your dependencies for OWC11.dll are either missing or unregistered.

Comment: I will try to re-install OWC11 and let you know. Can this issue be due to difference in the OWC.dll in test and production. I got a mail from web hosting administrator that it can be reason... check this link http://www.vbaccelerator.com/insprob.htm

Comment: Yes, this can absolutely happen on differing versions of a DLL.

Comment: I think I have found the problem... production server's OWC.dll verion is 12.0.4518.1014, but my dev server verion is 12.0.6502.5000(this is due to some service pack installation that updated the dll)

Answer (score 0):

The production server's OWC.dll verion is 12.0.4518.1014, but my dev server verion is 12.0.6502.5000(this is due to service pack installation that updated the dll). To reproduce the issue I created a sample VB project that refers owc11(*.*.6502.*) and then tried to the run the exe in the machine that has OWC11(*.*.4518.*) and I got the "429 - ActiveX component can't create object".

Answer (score 0):

In my case 32 bit applications support was turned off in IIS manager.
Here's how to turn it on:
http://www.depotsystems.com/ds_mobile_webhelp/webhelp/index.htm#page=Enabling_32_bit_mode.htm